# What is the theoretical flow rate of water through a tube leaving a container?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

The question comes from this image:

[image: experiment]

There is a container with $h$ amount of water above a hole of diameter $r$. This hole leads to a tube that the water exits through.

Using the pressure on both sides of the tube, how could one arrive at the theoretical flow rate?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation.

Comment: what are your thoughts on this so far?